# replaceCharactersInRange Not Working As Expected?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablestring

I have an NSMutableString that holds the string "I have ∞ Hours and ∞ Min to spare." and I am trying to replace the first ∞ with a "0" by doing

```
NSMutableString *timeString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"And I have ∞ Hours and ∞ Min to spare."];
NSLog(@"%@",timeString);
[timeString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(11,12) withString:@"0"];
NSLog(@"%@",timeString);
```

However, instead of only replacing the first ∞, it replaces the phrase "∞ Hours and "

Here is what is printed out in console:

```
And I have ∞ Hours and ∞ Min to spare.
And I have 0∞ Min to spare.
```

I don't understand why its deleting characters beyond the specified range.

Comment: The second value in NSMakeRange is length of the range, not position of the end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A range is made up of (location, length)

You are saying start at 11 and span 12 characters from there.
You;re effectively making a range of 11 to 22.

You need:

```
NSMakeRange(11,1)
```

Comment: thank you, it seems I got it mixed up with Java's substring method!

Answer (score 5):

The second parameter of a range is the length, not the ending position, so you should pass 1 there if you're trying to replace 1 character.

Answer (score 4):

The second value in `NSMakeRange` is length of the range, not position of the end.

Try with

```
NSMakeRange(11,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this ..!

```
NSMutableString *timeString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"And I have ∞ Hours and ∞ Min to spare."];

NSRange range = [timeString rangeOfString:@"∞"];
if (range.location != NSNotFound)
{
[timeString replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:@"0"];
}
```

Comment: If you were to do it this way it would be easier to use:
[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"∞" withString:@"0"]

Comment: You're correct. I do agree that if the posted code is the way that he is doing it, there are better (and more dynamic) ways to go about replacing certain pieces of text. I can think of quite a few.